# MSSQL Store Procedure Parameter Type With Using DB Table Column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, types, parameters, parameter-passing

Do you know how to get parameter type from database table column's type automatically?

For example,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UspS_GetProjectUser
    @UserName GETTYPE(Projects.username)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Projects (NOLOCK)
    WHERE Projects.expirationDate > GETDATE()
    AND Projects.username = @UserName
END
```

> GETTYPE(Projects.username) <<< I want to get the type of database table column's type ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible due to a catch-22.  The proc needs to be compiled and executed to invoke the GETTYPE function, but the proc cannot be compiled due to the unknown parameter data type.  This requires functionality that isn't currently in SQL Server.

I assume you want this feature, not to dynamically determine the data type at run time, but to avoid the development effort of matching the column data type manually (i.e. static typing at creation time).  There is merit to this but be aware that the caller should also specify the proper data type to avoid unexpected behavior due to implicit data type conversion.

Comment: Hi Dan,I know we can do that in PL/SQL but I'm researching that is there any way to do that in MS SQL. I wrote GETTYPE for example function. Is there any function to do that?

Comment: @SaygınKarahan, yes I understand GETTYPE was just an example.  This feature doesn't currently exist in T-SQL.  PL/SQL and T-SQL are different beasts.  Consider submitting an enhancement request on Connect (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/).